# How to get latest modified csv file values from ftp server and insert it into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, ftp

I am trying to get latest modified csv file values from ftp server  and insert it into mysql table. I don't have any idea how to do this.

I have to just read csv file from ftp server and get the latest data and insert into my  database. I am able to do this by downloading the latest file to my system. So i just have to do it without downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
            function getFtpConnection()
                {
                    static $connection = null;
                    if ($connection !== null) return $connection;
                    $host = '10.0.0.1';
                    $username = 'username';
                    $password = 'password';

                    // set up connection
                    if (!$connection = ftp_connect($host)) {
                        echo "couldn't connect to " . $host;
                        return false;
                    }
                    // login with username and password
                    if (!$login_result = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)) {
                        echo "couldn't connect as " . $username;
                        return false;
                    }

                    return $connection;
                }
        function getCsvFiles()
            {
                if (!$connection = getFtpConnection()) return false;

                $folder = '/folder/';
                // get list of files on given path
                $files = ftp_nlist($connection, $folder);
                if (!count($files)) {
                    echo "folder is empty";
                    return false;
                }
                $csvFiles = array();
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    if (!preg_match('~\w+.csv$~ism', $file)) continue;
                    $csvFiles[] = $folder . '/' . $file;
                }
                return $csvFiles;
            }
     function findNewestFile($files)
        {
            $mostRecent = array(
                'time' => 0,
                'file' => null
            );
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                // get the last modified time for the file
                $time = ftp_mdtm(getFtpConnection(), $file);
                if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) {
                    // this file is the most recent so far
                    $mostRecent['time'] = $time;
                    $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
                }
            }
            return $mostRecent['file'];
        }

// configuration
$dbtype = "mysql";
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

// All FTP files
$files = getCsvFiles();
// find newest file
$newestFile = findNewestFile($files);

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO csv_files (newestFile) VALUES (:newestFile)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':newestFile' => $newestFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three ways to do this.

You could look at timestamp / file size on the server and compare to the last file you imported, and see if there had been a change on the server.

You could instead of just using the same filename all the time, have a folder for the files on the server and put a time stamp in the name and use that to see if the file is new.

You could always download it and then do a compare and merge with the database...

Or my preferred way. After you have downloaded the file off the server, you delete (or better yet move) it on the server.

You need to use a few more ftp commands. You need some folders on the server, (say todo, and done) and above all you need to set up a user with permission to do the delete.
But you can make something very robust,  and recover from all sorts of failures simply by moving files from the done folder back in to the todo folder.

If you google ftp commands you'll find there more than just get.

One tip when you do something like this, bear Murphy in mind all the time. I guarantee, every now and then every part of what you hoped would happen, won't and every thing you really hoped wouldn't happen, will...